# Synchronize data between two sql server 2008 database with ado.net sync framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I have search but i can not get how to use ado.net sync framework.
can any body give me example code or samples ..or can share links that provide samples code of ado.net sync framework used for two sql server 2008 database Synchronization.

Answer (score 2):

I did synchronization a while ago and I used following tutorials

[Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928700.aspx), although this one is between SQL Server and SQL Express but it will work just fine between two SQL Servers.

Solution of some problems I faced can be found [here](http://evolpin.wordpress.com/2011/09/27/microsoft-sync-framework/)

[Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608.aspx) of how database synchronization works

In summary you need to do following

1. Provision Server database (only once)
2. Provision Client database (only once)
3. Do Synchronization